# parsing json to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

How can I parse this json `http://www.wind.it/it/negozi-wind/assets/lib/makerclusterplus/src/data.json` to NSDictionary so I could use it later with my map?

Comment: Well, you could spend 30 seconds using Google, or go straight to the spec for NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: I don't think the json file is valid. take out the var data

Comment: @Bejibun how can I do it in my app? not editing the json file

Comment: @HotLicks I think NSJSONSerialization doesn't help in this situation

Comment: And why do you think that?

Comment: @HotLicks  it returns me error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xa0823c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: That's because the JSON text did not start with an array or object.  Look at it.  JSON must always start with `[` or `{`.  Fix your JSON!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a web request and then use NSJSONSerialization.

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSError *urlError;

NSData *urldata = [NSURLConnection
                   sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                   returningResponse:&urlResponse
                   error:&urlError];

if (urldata) {
    NSMutableDictionary *profileDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urldata
                                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                                                           error:nil];
```

Comment: urldata returns me something like this: `<76617220 64617461 203d207b 2022636f 756e7422 3a203130 37383532 33362c0a 2270686f 746f7322 3a205b7b 2270686f 746f5f69 64223a20 32373933 322c2022 70686f74 6f5f7469 746c6522 3a202241 74617264` and the profileDictionary doesnt even intializes

Comment: That data is `var data = { "count": 10785236,"photos": [{"photo_id": 27932, "photo_title": "Atard`.  This is indeed what your URL returns, but it's not valid JSON -- the "var data =" does not belong there.  Fix your JSON and the above code will likely work (though brashy gets ten lashes with a wet noodle for not including error checking).